# UIView Scale animation with PivotX and pivotY

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am expanding a UIView with animation. here is the code I use ,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:PACKAGE_OTHER_VIEW_EXPAND_DURATION delay:PACKAGE_OTHER_VIEW_EXPAND_DURATION options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(viewX, viewY, PACKAGE_COLLAPSED_WIDTH, PACKAGE_HEIGHT)];
            } completion:NULL];
```

Now this animates the view to the new width expanding from Left to Right.

Now I need to expand views from **Right to left** and some views from **centre**, ie it expands to both sides.

How to do this in IOS OBJ C?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of basic arithmetic. The view does exactly what you tell it. Right now, you are telling it to expand to the right, because you are telling it to keep its origin (top left corner) unchanged.

So if that's not what you want, then don't do that! When you change the frame, calculate where the origin needs to be after the view expands, and use that, instead of `viewX` and `viewY`, as your new frame origin's `x` and `y` values.

In other words, to make the view expand to the left, *move* it to the left as you expand it.